# How do we filter all tokens belonging to a certain language using SOLR?

Tags: solr, information-retrieval

In my case, I want to filter out all English words from documents that predominantly contain Arabic words.

Comment: Is there anything you tried? Can you share it? As you are new, I strongly advice you reading our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I just want to know if such a filter exists. The alternatives I can think of  would be to continually update a stop-word list with English words returned or use a translator API to detect English words and remove them from the documents. Both of which are time consuming. I don't see how including any code would be useful in this case.

Comment: check this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Detecting+Languages+During+Indexing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is in Unicode, English and Arabic letters use different characters and you could filter them out with regular expressions.

So, in Solr, you would use something like [PatternReplaceFilterFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#PatternReplaceFilterFactory) and standard Java regular expressions. Notice that [Java's implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is actually very deep and supports scripts, blocks and other shortcut ways to use Unicode standard ranges.

Solr also has some ICU filters and tokenizers, but they are more for transliteration, transformation and normalization of complex characters.